# React-parameter passing-Do I need to declare a parameter name before i call/use it from child component to parent component?

Tags: reactjs, parameter-passing, create-react-app

Herer's my Parent and Child Components:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    
      this.state = {
         parentName: 'Parent'
      }
      this.greetParent = this.greetParent.bind(this)
    }
        // define a method call 'greetParent'
        greetParent(childName){
            alert(`Hello ${this.state.parentName} from ${childName}`)
        }
    
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent greetHandler={this.greetParent}></ChildComponent>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function ChildComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() =>props.greetHandler('child')}>Greet Parent</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Question:
I am wonder if I need declare a parameter name (in 'greetParent' method)before i call/use it from child component to parent component?
Do I just set any parameter value(in this case:'child' in ChildComponent) and it will automatically called in the ParentComponent(the 'greetParent' method)?

Answer (score 1):

Your example won't work because of the way you pass a callback to your child component. This is the issue:

```js
greetParent(childName) {
  // ...
}

render() {
  return <ChildComponent greetHandler={this.greetParent}></ChildComponent>
}
```

`this` reference is lost in `this.greetParent`, so calling `greetHandler('child')` will not use the expected `this`.

You can solve it differently:

1. Use an arrow function `greetHandler={(name) => this.greetParent(name)}`
2. Define `greetParent` as an arrow function:

```js
greetParent = (childName) => {
  alert(`Hello ${this.state.parentName} from ${childName}`)
};
```

This way `this.state` would give expected results.